# php filter array values based on key

Tags: php

I have two arrays: `$arr1` and `$arr2`. The two arrays have equal keys. I am merging the two arrays with duplicate keys. My output should show the duplicate keys with their corresponding values, for example

```
the key 22 exists and contains values 333,673,434
```

Below is my current code:

```
<?
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $i => $key) 
    {
        $result[] = array($key => $arr2[$i]);
    }

    print_r($result);
?>
```

Result as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [22] => 333
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [22] => 673
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [22] => 434
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [29] => 67
        )?>

    [4] => Array
        (
            [29] => 98
        )
[5] => Array
        (
            [29] => 656
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [28] => 12
        )
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? You only described a situation, not what your problem is. (And no...nobody will give you code...show us what you got, and we might be able to help you sort out any mistakes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 $result[] = array($key => $arr2[$i]);
```

To

```
 $result[$key][] = $arr2[$i];
```

You should get a array for each index. i.e. for 22, 28 and 29.

On 22, you should get a array containing 333,673 and 434.

If you need that value on comma separated value, then, try

```
if(is_array($result)&&!empty($result))
    foreach($result as $key => $item)
        $result_new[$key] = implode(',', $result[$key]);
print_r($result_new);
```